# Hide/Remove first line from total address block in JSP

Tags: regex, string, jsp, trim, texttrimming

I was calling a method as given here - to print the total address block.

```
Address add = AddressManager.getMyAddress(someId);
String totalAddr = FlexibleAddress.getAddressAsString(add , par1, par2);
out.print(totalAddr.toString());
```

The result of `totalAddr.toString()` is getting like ,

```
MyName
AddressLine1
AddressLine2
City
```

I need to remove the first line (ie `MyName` here) from this total address block. I have to cut the first line from the jsp page where it is displaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the below code

```
totalAddr = totalAddr.substring(totalAddr.indexOf('\n')+1);
out.print(totalAddr.toString());
```

Comment: In the getAddressAsString method how the new lines are defined? if it is defined using <br> instead of finding the index of \n try with <br>.

Comment: I have tried with <BR>. In my java <BR> was using. But now I am getting like,

`BR>AddressLine1
AddressLine2
City`. Why is that BR> is coming at the beginning. Otherwise its working.

Comment: If <BR> works fine then instead of incrementing the index +1 try incrementing  the index +4 as <BR> contains 4 characters.